# Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col5

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, import

Trying to Import data from another sheet once another column value is equal the "yes"

Tried the following:

```
=query(ImportRange("1yRp2JG_ttPbly5A7HmgJZwH-Xn8l3GKJxo8DshzffOQ","validated!E2:E"),"SELECT Col5 WHERE Col12=" & "'" & L2 & "'", Yes)
```

Gives me the above error

Answer (score 0):

When importing only two columns (B and C) there is no Column 5, nor when importing only one (E). Maybe you want to import B:F but if using JavaScript in this case you should provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).